# Test coverage with SonarQube bitbucket plugin in pull requests

Tags: sonarqube, bitbucket, sonarqube-scan

I have the following setup:

- Bamboo runs builds on every commit on feature branches, including
  Bamboo SonarQube plugin
- Analysis, including test code coverage
  displays in SonarQube.

We installed SonarQube plugin on the Stash Server, and it mostly works (quality gate, etc), but code coverage does not show up in diff in pull requests. What needs to be enabled to that to work?

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Code Coverage plugin](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.atlassian.bitbucket.code-coverage-plugin/server/overview) to integrate coverage information into stash pull-requests. In order to use it, you need to:

- Install plugin on your Bitbucket server
- Publish coverage information from your branch build. You could use [maven client](https://bitbucket.org/atlassian/bitbucket-code-coverage/src/master/code-coverage-maven-plugin/) or [nodejs client](https://bitbucket.org/atlassian/code-coverage-client/) depending on your tech stack.

That doesn't require SonarQube at all, since all information stored on Bitbucket itself.

Answer (score 0):

Pull Request analysis doesn't (yet?) handle code coverage; it only looks at new issues (other than, of course, issues for things that are calculated server-side like inadequate test coverage).

Comment: Thank you! The video here https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/ch.mibex.stash.sonar4stash/server/overview shows that functionality.... Do you know if and when it will be available?

Comment: that's entirely outside my realm